# How to implement early stopping in bert fine tuning for token classification

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I want to fine-tune Bert using my custom dataset for token classification. I am very new to this, I did find a code for fine-tuning, but it’s getting hard to determine the right number of epochs and learning rate. I have a dataset of 3000 sentences training it 3 and 40 times shows a difference. Is there way to determine it or implement any kind of logic to get the right number of epochs? Would appreciate it if someone could help me.

```
from transformers import pipeline
from seqeval.metrics import classification_report

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertConfig, BertForTokenClassification
from torch import cuda
device = 'cuda' if cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'


file = "/content/sample_data.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(file, encoding='unicode_escape')

frequencies = data.Tag.value_counts()


tags = {}
for tag, count in zip(frequencies.index, frequencies):
    if tag != "O":
        if tag[2:5] not in tags.keys():
            tags[tag[2:5]] = count
        else:
            tags[tag[2:5]] += count
    continue

# pandas has a very handy "forward fill" function to fill missing values based on the last upper non-nan value
data = data.fillna(method='ffill')


# let's create a new column called "sentence" which groups the words by sentence
data['sentence'] = data[['Sentence #','Word','Tag']].groupby(['Sentence #'])['Word'].transform(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
# let's also create a new column called "word_labels" which groups the tags by sentence
data['word_labels'] = data[['Sentence #','Word','Tag']].groupby(['Sentence #'])['Tag'].transform(lambda x: ','.join(x))
data.head()

label2id = {k: v for v, k in enumerate(data.Tag.unique())}
id2label = {v: k for v, k in enumerate(data.Tag.unique())}

data = data[["sentence", "word_labels"]].drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)


MAX_LEN = 128
TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE = 4
VALID_BATCH_SIZE = 2
EPOCHS = 8
LEARNING_RATE = 2e-05
MAX_GRAD_NORM = 10
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')


def tokenize_and_preserve_labels(sentence, text_labels, tokenizer):
    """
    Word piece tokenization makes it difficult to match word labels
    back up with individual word pieces. This function tokenizes each
    word one at a time so that it is easier to preserve the correct
    label for each subword. It is, of course, a bit slower in processing
    time, but it will help our model achieve higher accuracy.
    """

    tokenized_sentence = []
    labels = []

    sentence = sentence.strip()

    for word, label in zip(sentence.split(), text_labels.split(",")):

        # Tokenize the word and count # of subwords the word is broken into
        tokenized_word = tokenizer.tokenize(word)
        n_subwords = len(tokenized_word)

        # Add the tokenized word to the final tokenized word list
        tokenized_sentence.extend(tokenized_word)

        # Add the same label to the new list of labels `n_subwords` times
        labels.extend([label] * n_subwords)

    return tokenized_sentence, labels


class dataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dataframe, tokenizer, max_len):
        self.len = len(dataframe)
        self.data = dataframe
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.max_len = max_len

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        # step 1: tokenize (and adapt corresponding labels)
        sentence = self.data.sentence[index]
        word_labels = self.data.word_labels[index]
        tokenized_sentence, labels = tokenize_and_preserve_labels(sentence, word_labels, self.tokenizer)

        # step 2: add special tokens (and corresponding labels)
        tokenized_sentence = ["[CLS]"] + tokenized_sentence + ["[SEP]"]  # add special tokens
        labels.insert(0, "O")  # add outside label for [CLS] token
        labels.insert(-1, "O")  # add outside label for [SEP] token

        # step 3: truncating/padding
        maxlen = self.max_len

        if (len(tokenized_sentence) > maxlen):
            # truncate
            tokenized_sentence = tokenized_sentence[:maxlen]
            labels = labels[:maxlen]
        else:
            # pad
            tokenized_sentence = tokenized_sentence + ['[PAD]' for _ in range(maxlen - len(tokenized_sentence))]
            labels = labels + ["O" for _ in range(maxlen - len(labels))]

        # step 4: obtain the attention mask
        attn_mask = [1 if tok != '[PAD]' else 0 for tok in tokenized_sentence]

        # step 5: convert tokens to input ids
        ids = self.tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokenized_sentence)

        label_ids = [label2id[label] for label in labels]
        # the following line is deprecated
        # label_ids = [label if label != 0 else -100 for label in label_ids]

        return {
            'ids': torch.tensor(ids, dtype=torch.long),
            'mask': torch.tensor(attn_mask, dtype=torch.long),
            # 'token_type_ids': torch.tensor(token_ids, dtype=torch.long),
            'targets': torch.tensor(label_ids, dtype=torch.long)
        }

    def __len__(self):
        return self.len

train_size = 0.8
train_dataset = data.sample(frac=train_size, random_state=200)
test_dataset = data.drop(train_dataset.index).reset_index(drop=True)
train_dataset = train_dataset.reset_index(drop=True)

training_set = dataset(train_dataset, tokenizer, MAX_LEN)
testing_set = dataset(test_dataset, tokenizer, MAX_LEN)

# print the first 30 tokens and corresponding labels
for token, label in zip(tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(training_set[0]["ids"][:30]),
                        training_set[0]["targets"][:30]):
    print('{0:10}  {1}'.format(token, id2label[label.item()]))


train_params = {'batch_size': TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE,
                'shuffle': True,
                'num_workers': 0
                }

test_params = {'batch_size': VALID_BATCH_SIZE,
                'shuffle': True,
                'num_workers': 0
                }

training_loader = DataLoader(training_set, **train_params)
testing_loader = DataLoader(testing_set, **test_params)

model = BertForTokenClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased',
                                                   num_labels=len(id2label),
                                                   id2label=id2label,
                                                   label2id=label2id)
model.to(device)


ids = training_set[0]["ids"].unsqueeze(0)
mask = training_set[0]["mask"].unsqueeze(0)
targets = training_set[0]["targets"].unsqueeze(0)
ids = ids.to(device)
mask = mask.to(device)
targets = targets.to(device)
outputs = model(input_ids=ids, attention_mask=mask, labels=targets)
initial_loss = outputs[0]
tr_logits = outputs[1]


optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(params=model.parameters(), lr=LEARNING_RATE)


# Defining the training function on the 80% of the dataset for tuning the bert model
def train(epoch):
    tr_loss, tr_accuracy = 0, 0
    nb_tr_examples, nb_tr_steps = 0, 0
    tr_preds, tr_labels = [], []
    # put model in training mode
    model.train()

    for idx, batch in enumerate(training_loader):

        ids = batch['ids'].to(device, dtype=torch.long)
        mask = batch['mask'].to(device, dtype=torch.long)
        targets = batch['targets'].to(device, dtype=torch.long)

        outputs = model(input_ids=ids, attention_mask=mask, labels=targets)
        loss, tr_logits = outputs.loss, outputs.logits
        tr_loss += loss.item()

        nb_tr_steps += 1
        nb_tr_examples += targets.size(0)

        if idx % 100 == 0:
            loss_step = tr_loss / nb_tr_steps
            print(f"Training loss per 100 training steps: {loss_step}")

        # compute training accuracy
        flattened_targets = targets.view(-1)  # shape (batch_size * seq_len,)
        active_logits = tr_logits.view(-1, model.num_labels)  # shape (batch_size * seq_len, num_labels)
        flattened_predictions = torch.argmax(active_logits, axis=1)  # shape (batch_size * seq_len,)
        # now, use mask to determine where we should compare predictions with targets (includes [CLS] and [SEP] token predictions)
        active_accuracy = mask.view(-1) == 1  # active accuracy is also of shape (batch_size * seq_len,)
        targets = torch.masked_select(flattened_targets, active_accuracy)
        predictions = torch.masked_select(flattened_predictions, active_accuracy)

        tr_preds.extend(predictions)
        tr_labels.extend(targets)

        tmp_tr_accuracy = accuracy_score(targets.cpu().numpy(), predictions.cpu().numpy())
        tr_accuracy += tmp_tr_accuracy

        # gradient clipping
        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(
            parameters=model.parameters(), max_norm=MAX_GRAD_NORM
        )

        # backward pass
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    epoch_loss = tr_loss / nb_tr_steps
    tr_accuracy = tr_accuracy / nb_tr_steps
    print(f"Training loss epoch: {epoch_loss}")
    print(f"Training accuracy epoch: {tr_accuracy}")

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    print(f"Training epoch: {epoch + 1}")
    train(epoch)


def valid(model, testing_loader):
    # put model in evaluation mode
    model.eval()

    eval_loss, eval_accuracy = 0, 0
    nb_eval_examples, nb_eval_steps = 0, 0
    eval_preds, eval_labels = [], []

    with torch.no_grad():
        for idx, batch in enumerate(testing_loader):

            ids = batch['ids'].to(device, dtype=torch.long)
            mask = batch['mask'].to(device, dtype=torch.long)
            targets = batch['targets'].to(device, dtype=torch.long)

            outputs = model(input_ids=ids, attention_mask=mask, labels=targets)
            loss, eval_logits = outputs.loss, outputs.logits

            eval_loss += loss.item()

            nb_eval_steps += 1
            nb_eval_examples += targets.size(0)

            if idx % 100 == 0:
                loss_step = eval_loss / nb_eval_steps
                print(f"Validation loss per 100 evaluation steps: {loss_step}")

            # compute evaluation accuracy
            flattened_targets = targets.view(-1)  # shape (batch_size * seq_len,)
            active_logits = eval_logits.view(-1, model.num_labels)  # shape (batch_size * seq_len, num_labels)
            flattened_predictions = torch.argmax(active_logits, axis=1)  # shape (batch_size * seq_len,)
            # now, use mask to determine where we should compare predictions with targets (includes [CLS] and [SEP] token predictions)
            active_accuracy = mask.view(-1) == 1  # active accuracy is also of shape (batch_size * seq_len,)
            targets = torch.masked_select(flattened_targets, active_accuracy)
            predictions = torch.masked_select(flattened_predictions, active_accuracy)

            eval_labels.extend(targets)
            eval_preds.extend(predictions)

            tmp_eval_accuracy = accuracy_score(targets.cpu().numpy(), predictions.cpu().numpy())
            eval_accuracy += tmp_eval_accuracy

    # print(eval_labels)
    # print(eval_preds)

    labels = [id2label[id.item()] for id in eval_labels]
    predictions = [id2label[id.item()] for id in eval_preds]

    # print(labels)
    # print(predictions)

    eval_loss = eval_loss / nb_eval_steps
    eval_accuracy = eval_accuracy / nb_eval_steps
    print(f"Validation Loss: {eval_loss}")
    print(f"Validation Accuracy: {eval_accuracy}")

    return labels, predictions

labels, predictions = valid(model, testing_loader)

print(classification_report([labels], [predictions]))

sentence = "John went to london."

inputs = tokenizer(sentence, padding='max_length', truncation=True, max_length=MAX_LEN, return_tensors="pt")

# move to gpu
ids = inputs["input_ids"].to(device)
mask = inputs["attention_mask"].to(device)
# forward pass
outputs = model(ids, mask)
logits = outputs[0]

active_logits = logits.view(-1, model.num_labels) # shape (batch_size * seq_len, num_labels)
flattened_predictions = torch.argmax(active_logits, axis=1) # shape (batch_size*seq_len,) - predictions at the token level

tokens = tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(ids.squeeze().tolist())
token_predictions = [id2label[i] for i in flattened_predictions.cpu().numpy()]
wp_preds = list(zip(tokens, token_predictions)) # list of tuples. Each tuple = (wordpiece, prediction)

word_level_predictions = []
for pair in wp_preds:
  if (pair[0].startswith(" ##")) or (pair[0] in ['[CLS]', '[SEP]', '[PAD]']):
    # skip prediction
    continue
  else:
    word_level_predictions.append(pair[1])

# we join tokens, if they are not special ones
str_rep = " ".join([t[0] for t in wp_preds if t[0] not in ['[CLS]', '[SEP]', '[PAD]']]).replace(" ##", "")
print(str_rep)
print(word_level_predictions)


pipe = pipeline(task="token-classification", model=model.to("cpu"), tokenizer=tokenizer, aggregation_strategy="simple")
pipe("my date of birth is 23-09-2023, Jakes's phone numbers are +1 (414)-123 6512")
print("saving model")
pat = folder/output"
model.save_pretrained(pat)
tokenizer.save_pretrained(pat)
```

Im very new to fine tuning, how to determine/implement the right number of epochs and learning rate logic in the above code. Would appreaciate the help.